# What is the need of using IN and OUT state in the following script?

Tags: c, string, io, getchar

Hello everyone I just started learning C through THE c PROGRAMMING LANGUAGE Second Edition
by Brian. W.Kernighnan (ISBN-13: 978-8131704943)

So here is a script which counts the characters, line, words

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define IN  1
#define OUT 0

main()
{
    int c, nl, nw, nc, state; 
    /* c = input, nl = new line, nc = new character, nw = new word, state = (IN/OUT) */
    state = OUT;
    nl = nw = nc = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        ++nc;
        if (c == '\n')
            ++nl;
        if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')
            state = OUT;
        else if (state == OUT)
        {
            state = IN;
            ++nw;
        }
    }
    printf(" The number of lines is: %d,\n The number of words is: %d,\n The number of characters is: %d. \n", nl, nw, nc);
}
```

However I made a script which does the following without the need of defining state IN and OUT

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    int nw, nl, nc, c ;
    nl = nw = nc = c = 0 ;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        ++nc;
        if (c == '\n')
            ++nl;
        else if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')
            ++nw;
    }
    printf("Words:%d \nCharacters:%d \nLines:%d", nw, nc, nl);
}
```

So what is the difference between these two, why does the author use the state to define IN and OUT ??

[EDIT]
Oh! I see so the script is just to avoid two things :
1. To avoid word count when there are more than one spaces following the word.
2. Secondly my script would count n-2 words I suppose if proper spacing is done.
Which makes the author's script more fullproof.....Is there anything else except these two ??

And thank You for your answes too....

P.S: I'm sorry this is a bit off-topic is it ok to label the question [SOLVED] or is there any other way of doing this ??

Comment: Try an input with multiple spaces between words, or empty lines, and you'll see the difference.

Comment: He probably could have chosen better names for his state, like ON and OFF and instead of `state` called it `word_state` or something like that, but the function is still the same

Comment: @staticx I find the names good. It's `IN`- or `OUT`side of a word.

Comment: @leemes: Maybe cursor_state then

Comment: @staticx Personally I'd named it `within_word` with the type `bool` and got rid of those unnecessary macros. But I'm not sure when `bool` got invented... ;)

Comment: @HansPassant Well, `bool` was (or still is?) no builtin type of C...

Comment: @leemes: True. The book is from around 1988. C didn't have bool in the initial implementation (1972) per Wikipedia. I guess old habits die hard.

Comment: @leemes: C99 has it. "Standard C (since C99) and several dialects of C such as Objective-C provide definitions of a Boolean type as an integer type and macros for "false" and "true" as 0 and 1, respectively. Thus logical values can be stored in integer variables, and used anywhere integers would be valid, including in indexing, arithmetic, parsing, and formatting. This approach ("Boolean values are just integers") has been retained in all later versions of C."

Comment: @leemes: A book from the 80s is unlikely to mention the type `bool`. Or to waste precious bytes on comments and descriptive names, for that matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your version is slightly different from his one: in your program, if you have N consecutive spaces, they will be considered as N - 1 words, because for every space you add one to the word count. Also, the last input word won't be considered.

Answer (score 2):

`IN` literally means "inside a word" and `OUT` literally means "outside a word". He is tracking the state of the proverbial cursor as he moves through the lines.

Comment: I had understood what the script meant, but wanted to know what is the difference between mine and author's scripts (which is solved too......)..Thanks though

Comment: @ArchKudo: That's not what this comment says: "why does the author use the state to define IN and OUT "

Comment: Oh! I'm sorry my bad, I really meant why does the author use IN and OUT  in his script instead of my script which doesn't,I'm yet again sorry for the confusion though

Comment: @ArchKudo: Because he is tracking where a word starts and begins to count the number of words. If you don't use it, then you will count things that are not words such as multiple spaces, tabs, or newlines. He keeps setting the state to `OUT` until he doesn't see those characters anymore, then he knows that it must be the start of a word. Once he reaches a space, newline, or tab then he knows he is "out of a word". Notice that he only counts it once.