# How can I enumerate text read from a file line by line, and find the line with the most characters and words in C?

Tags: c++, c, io, lines

I'm currently writing a program that is supposed to read from a text file (fed to the program via the command line), and then enumerate and print out each line and provide information on the number of words, characters, and lines, as well as information on which line has the most characters/words.

So far I've been able to get it to count the number of words, characters, and lines but am having trouble finding a way to enumerate and print each line back out and find which lines have the most characters/words.

Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define IN 1
#define OUT 0

int main( )
{
int line, word, character, state, place, flag
    maxW, maxC;
state = OUT;
line = word = character = 0;
while( (place = getchar()) != EOF ) {

    ++character;
    flag = IN;
    printf("%c", place);

    if( place == '\n' ) {
        ++line;
        printf("%d: ", (line + 1));
        flag = IN;
    }
    if(flag == IN) {


    }

    if( place == ' ' || place == '\n' || place == '\t' )
        state = OUT;
    else if( state == OUT ) {
        state = IN;
        ++word;
    }

}
printf("%d lines, %d words, & %d characters.\n", line, word, character);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you OK with a c# solution? Or just tagged every language *similar!* to `C`

Comment: Measure the line length in words or characters. Is it longer than the longest so far? If so, hold on to it. Repeat to the end of the file.

Comment: The task would be easier if you read lines with `fgets`.

Comment: You "got it to count words" by copying the code from, for example, http://stackoverflow.com/q/23609836/2564301?

Comment: @Jongware Actually, no. I read it from a textbook that suggested copying it's code and taking it further by trying to enumerate and and compare amounts of words.

Comment: That's fair. Reason I asked is because the line `maxW, maxC` seems tacked on to texisting code without any regard to the C syntax.

Comment: @Jongware Oh, I see. I was considering testing out the use of those to find my maxes but didn't end up using them yet. The code I've posted is very rough.

Answer (score 1):

Create a local highest character count and a current character count

```
int highestCharCount = 0;
int currentCharCount = 0;
```

Keep track of the character count

```
++currentCharCount;
```

Each loop check if the character count is higher than the highest, if it is, change the highest.

```
If(currentCharCount > highestCharCount){
    highestCharCount = currentCharCount ;
}
```

Reset it at the same time as you get a new line character.

```
if( place == '\n' ) {
    currentCharCount = 0;
    ++line;
    printf("%d: ", (line + 1));
    flag = IN;
}
```

And with that, you will end up with the highest char number.